# How to upload >250 mb size using php ,ajax post in cakephp application?

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, nginx

I am using jax post method to upload data from php to server using cakephp application, upto 250 mb is uploading and I am using nginx server. Greater than 250 mb throwing post error. Is there any other way to upload large file sizes.
I have done all changes in php.ini file: max_execution_time, upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, max_input_time. Still the issue remains same. This issue is related to ajax post method. How to solve this?

Comment: I recommend using chunked file upload handling: e.g. https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload - there is also a Cake plugin for that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have seen that link and gone through the documentation, but i didn't get  how to integrate that pugin or basic upload flow inside cakephp using View, Cotroller and after that with uploaded data some process need to be done.